# Bash script to get into a running container and then run another bash script from that container

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, docker, dockerfile

I have a shell script which runs as follows :

```
image_id=$(docker ps -a | grep postgres | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
full_id=$(docker ps -a --no-trunc -q | grep $image_id)
docker exec -i -t $full_id bash
```

When I run this from the base linux OS, I expect to actually enter the postgres container which is a running container. But the issue is that the shell script hangs on 3rd line during ' docker exec' step.

My end goal is using the bash script, enter a running postgres container and run another bash script inside that container. 
However the same command when I run it from command line, it works fine and gets me into the postgres container.

Please help, I have spent hours and hours to solve this but no progress.

Thanks again

Comment: What's the final command you want to run in the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is a bit more complex than it needs to be.

Docker [`ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) can filter containers directly with the `--filter=` option

```
docker ps --no-trunc --quiet --filter="ancestor=postgres"
```

You can also [`--name`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name-name) containers when you run them which will be less fraught with danger than the script you are attempting

```
docker run --detach --name postgres_whatever postgres
docker exec -ti postgres_whatever bash
```

I'm not sure that your script is hanging as opposed to sitting there waiting for input. Try running a command directly

#### Using naming

`exec_test.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker exec postgres_whatever echo "I have run the test"
```

When run

```
$ ./exec_test.sh
I have run the test
```

#### Without naming

`exec_filter_test.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
id=$(docker ps --no-trunc --quiet --filter="ancestor=postgres")
[ -z "$id" ] && echo "no id" && exit 1
docker exec "${id}" echo "I have run the test"
```

When run

```
$ ./exec_filter_test.sh 
I have run the test
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. That really helped .